# If I boot Ubuntu from dvd on windows 7 will I have to keep changing the bios whenever I want to switch between OS's

Tags: boot, windows-7, dvd

I have ubuntu 14.04.1 burned on a DVD I was wondering if I did go in the BIOS on my windows 7 machine and chose boot from CD will I still be able to boot windows 7 later on without disabling the boot from CD. What Im trying to say is how will I safely swith between my main OS (windows 7) and ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to run Ubuntu off DVD without installing it. Yes the DVD does have a "try ubuntu", but using that is pretty limited. Mostly, it won't save any changes. Any time you boot off that DVD you get a stock environment every time.

If you have no interest in dual booting Ubuntu and Windows, and if your computer supports it, I would  use a USB drive.

From Windows download and install Linux Live USB Creator. Once you get in there select the USB device and set to write the Ubuntu image you downloaded.

Now the important part. Notice the persistence section. Set this to what your USB device will allow.  This is where all your changes and downloads will be saved.

As an example, if you have  a 20 Gig USB drive, the Ubuntu image will take about 4-5 Gigs maybe, so you could get a persistent partition of say 15 Gigs. 
Something like that. Maybe little less.

So basically you have a portable Ubuntu with a 10-15 Gig partition that will save your installs, changes, documents and media.

The bigger the drive the bigger the persistence you can have.

Depending on the computer, you can press f9 (or some other fkey) or use bios to boot from USB when want Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You will boot to your main OS on hard drive if no bootable CD/DVD is present in the machine. You can also check order of booting devices in your BIOS. The boot sequence than tries them in the order specified there until it finds some bootable medium.

Comment: How would I check the sequence

Comment: Depends on your BIOS but it should be called something like 'boot sequence' (see this pic: http://motherboards-reviews.com/motherboards/MSI/G31TM-P35/images/MSI_G31TM-P35_BIOS_Boot_Sequence.jpg) EDIT: better pic here: http://www.hirensbootcd.org/images/change_boot_order/biosbootmenu-remdevices.jpg